# Covert all column headers to a single column in dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe looks like below:

```
   date       A       B       C
2015-01-25  0.97    0.33    0.65
2015-02-01  0.23    0.02    0.67
```

My goal is to covert the df to a new format like below:

```
  date     Type Value
2015-01-25  A   0.97
2015-02-01  A   0.23
2015-01-25  B   0.33
2015-02-01  B   0.08
2015-01-25  C   0.65
2015-02-01  C   0.67
```

which means move all the columns to the rows as a new column as type, and put their value for each date as a unique columns, I did some search on Google, but still cannot find a right solution.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) method like this:

```
>>> df = df.melt(id_vars=['date'], var_name='Type', value_name='Value')
>>> print(df)
         date Type  Value
0  2015-01-25    A   0.97
1  2015-02-01    A   0.23
2  2015-01-25    B   0.33
3  2015-02-01    B   0.02
4  2015-01-25    C   0.65
5  2015-02-01    C   0.67
```

Comment: Ok, I am sorry.

Comment: Ya, it is up to you if remove answer or not ;) Obviously if youare rep hunter not removed ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [melt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
df.melt(id_vars='date', var_name='Type', value_name='Values')
```